# How to create a separate dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have input data which looks like this:

DF()

| **symbol | sample1 | sample2 | sample3** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cohort | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| gene1 | 2334 | 99467 | 3782 |
| gene2 | 3889 | 4893 | 22891 |

and I want to separate "Cohort" and the column names and make a separate data frame. Something like this:

| symbol | Cohort |
| --- | --- |
| sample1 | 0 |
| sample2 | 1 |

I tried this:

```
DF<- data %>% filter(row_number() == 1) 
data1<-t(DF)
```

but got this:

|  | V1 |
| --- | --- |
| symbol | Cohort |
| sample1 | 0 |
| sample2 | 1 |

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: When importing the files you can choose starting rows, and how many rows. That way you can read the same file twice and get 2 dataframes. One would exclude 1st row, the 2nd would keep only 1st row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data set is quite messy, but you can do:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  filter(symbol == "Cohort") %>% 
  t() %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  tibble::rownames_to_column() %>% 
  janitor::row_to_names(1)

   symbol Cohort
2 sample1      0
3 sample2      1
4 sample3      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit tough to parse, but I think the code below should help.

I've used [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org) which is a common package for reshaping and tidying data ([R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/) is a good resource for this and more).

There are alternatives such as `reshape` in base R, though I'm not very familiar with that.

What I'm doing is:

- Loading tidyverse with `library`
- Creating your sample dataframe using `tribble`

On this df:

- `pivot_longer` stacks the columns defined by the `cols` argument

  - `starts_with` selects every column whose name begins with "sample"
- `filter` removes any column where "Symbol" is not equal to "Cohort"
- `select` chooses specific columns and renames in a single step

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~"symbol", ~"sample1", ~"sample2", ~"sample3",
  "Cohort", 0, 1, 0,
  "gene1", 2334, 99467, 3782,
  "gene2", 3889, 4893, 22891
)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("sample")
  ) %>% 
  filter(symbol == "Cohort") %>% 
  select(symbol = name,
         cohort = value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the file twice to get genes and cohort rows separately, for example:

```
myFile = "symbol    sample1 sample2 sample3
Cohort  0   1   0
gene1   2334    99467   3782
gene2   3889    4893    22891
"

#get gene names ignoring cohort row
myCols <- names(read.table(text = myFile, nrows = 1, header = TRUE))
d1 <- read.table(text = myFile, skip = 2, col.names = myCols)

#get cohort row as vector
cohort <- read.table(text = myFile, skip = 1, nrows = 1)
cohort <- as.numeric(cohort[, -1])
```

Now convert gene dataset into a matrix, with rownames as gene names and column names as sample IDs. It will make future calculations/subsets more efficient.

```
m <- as.matrix(d1[, -1])
dimnames(m) <- list(d1[, 1], colnames(d1)[ -1 ])
m
#       sample1 sample2 sample3
# gene1    2334   99467    3782
# gene2    3889    4893   22891
```

For example, to get gene1 for samples from cohort 1:

```
m[ "gene1", cohort == 1]
# [1] 99467
```